# Recommendation for a good entity relationship diagram building tool for occasional usage?

Tags: database-design, diagram, entity-relationship

Freeware is a plus. Could you also describe with one sentence why it should be good enough for occasional usage?

Edit: You might check this cool [link](http://www.reference.com/browse/entity-relationship+diagram) , providing more info about entity relationship diagrams and tools

Edit: For the chosen answer couple of tips
 - click on entity even it looks like circle and type the name and Enter - it will give you the Entity box
 - Click on association , Ctrl + L would give you the nice line

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net) with the ER extension. It is totally free, stable and easy to learn.

Update: 09.10.2017: StarUML is not free anymore!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
StarUML seemed to answer at most the "occasional usage requirement". And it is freeware.

Comment: Landed here and wanted to use StarUML but, v2 is not free.

Answer (score 5):

Dbdesigner 4 at http://www.fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/downloads.php. It's free, easy to use, does reverse engineering.

Comment: By far the best free tool i've seen or used... thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

yEd is a powerful desktop application that can be used to quickly and effectively generate high-quality diagrams for free.

http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html

MySQL Workbench is also excellent

Answer (score 2):

Oracle Data Modeling - works with Oracle, MsSQL and DB2

MySQL Workbench - works with MySQL

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using Visual Studio - it has it's own diagram tool integrated. Works good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Dezign for Databases](http://www.datanamic.com/dezign/index.html). It's very easy to use (but powerful enough for most development tasks, supports a wide range of databases and finally the price (~245 $) is not that much. Personally I'm very happy with the tool.

Answer (score 0):

Toad Data Modeler - costs 400 USD, but is worth the price. Currently it offers many nice features, and they are still adding more. There is an excellent user community around this tool, and it is quite easy to stay in touch with development team.

Comment: Can't knock the tool - I like Toad, but considering there are free tools 400 USD might be a bit expensive for infrequent modelling

Comment: I don't think this answer deserved a down vote...

Answer (score 0):

SQL Power Architect Community Edition at http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect_download_os. A friend of mine used it for a project and said it was easy, reasonably powerful, and free.

Answer (score 0):

I've said this in another answer but I have two more suggestions:

1) No-one seems to have mentioned the great tool which my uni recommends. Its a 620K download called `ER-Assistant`. Its basic plain black/white `ERD`'s but some like that. Its free and uses Crows foot notation, but windows only.
http://highered.mcgraw-hill.com/sites/0072942207/student_view0/e_r_assistant.html

2) Also Lucid Charts is decent. Its free to use until you reach very complex diagrams. Its web based so obviously platform agnostic
https://www.lucidchart.com