# A class diagram is to a program as a ________ is to a database?

Tags: database, database-design, reverse-engineering

What is the analogue of a class diagram in the world of relational/SQL databases?

And what is a good way to generate this equivalent in Eclipse?  Free is better, but good and commercial is fine as well.

Answer (score 13):

An "entity diagram" or "entity relationship diagram"?

And how about [Eclipse ERD](http://eclipse-erd.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Is a schema diagram the same thing as an entity diagram/entity relationship diagram?

Answer (score 5):

A schema diagram.  Here's [an example](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-GEF-editor/gef-schema-editor.html).

See this related question for example of tools you can use to build these things:

- [Recommendation for a good entity relationship diagram building tool for occasional usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857488/recommendation-for-a-good-entity-relationship-diagram-building-tool-for-occasiona)

Comment: Is an entity diagram/entity relationship diagram the same as a schema diagram?

Comment: @unknown: Yes, as far as I know they mean the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

[Entity Relationship Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model) (or model).  I don't use Eclipse much anymore, but you can make nice diagrams (for free) in [NetBeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/ERDSupport).

Answer (score 1):

I know there are different views on this topic, but I prefer to use **UML class diagrams** for modeling relational databases and for example Scott W. Ambler uses UML for data models in his books - see [this page](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/umlDataModelingProfile.html). If you are going to use [Hibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/)/[EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/)(former Oracle TopLink)/[JPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API), then [**HiberObjects**](http://objectgeneration.com/eclipse/) is an excellent **Eclipse plugin**. I love the way you can create test data using it. The plugin is steadily improving and my experience when reporting bugs is that they are quickly resolved. I also have had good use of the scripting capabilities, generating DAO class tailored to my projects. If you pay, there's an [extension to import databases](http://objectgeneration.com/eclipse/10-Import%20from%20Database.html) too.